# return FirebaseObjectObservable from Observable.mergeMap

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm creating an abstract data service class for my application, for that I have an abstract method `getBaseUri` which returns an `Observable<string>` (because sometimes you need the user id in the uri, meaning that it has to be an `Observable`).

The issue is that because the base oservable is an Observable, the final observable of my list is an `Observable<T>`, not a `FirebaseObjectObservable <T>`.

Here is what I'm currently using:

The abstract method:

`protected abstract getBaseUri(): Observable<string>;`

my `listRef` getter:

```
private get oneRef(uid: string): FirebaseObjectObservable <T> {
    return this.getBaseUri().mergeMap(uri => this.firebase.object(`${uri}/${uid}`));
}
```

The current runtime error is:

> ERROR TypeError: this.oneRef(...).update is not a function.

Comment: Please, explain your case in details. What do you try to do? Please, post all relevant code. The snippets you've posted just prove that an observable won't be FirebaseObjectObservable indeed and thus won't have `update` method.

Comment: @estus What I'm trying to do is pretty simple, I want to create a FirebaseObjectObservable from another observable. I want to do that because I want user-related data, meaning that I need the user uid for the data path (/users/{uid}/...). to get the uid, I need an observable because I want to use the authState observable.

Comment: You can't, because it will be converted to regular observable when being used like that. This is how observables work. If you're interested in possible workarounds, consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: So there's no way to build a FirebaseObjectObservable from a standard observable? I'd like to provide a mcve but without a firebase connection, I don't know how to.

Comment: Since FB observable just slightly extends Rx observable, https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/firebase_object_observable.ts#L8 this likely should be achievable, just not in a way you expect it, and it will be quite messy. This is the reason why decorating an observable with new methods like `update` wasn't a good idea. I'd suggest to discuss this issue in Angular Firebase repo.

Comment: @estus Alright, I created an issue on angularfire2 repo, in case you want to follow the resolution of it: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1150

Comment: You can't call update() on an Observable. [It doesn't have that method.](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html). What's the goal here? See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).